# Order total sales by month

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I am printing out the total sales for each state so long as they have over $6000 in sales for that month. The results need to be ordered by month(descending order). I noticed that I got 2 results for Texas for the same month. So what that tells me is it is just looking for individual sales over $6,000 even though I have a sum(so.total) which I thought would give the total sales for state ordered by the month. Not sure how to break down the sales by each individual month if the order_date field has day-month-year in it.(Using Oracle 10g)

Input:

```
 SELECT c.state "State",to_char(so.order_date, 'Month')"Month", sum(so.total)"Sales"
 FROM a_customer c
 JOIN a_sales_order so ON c.customer_id=so.customer_id
 GROUP BY c.state, so.order_date
 HAVING sum(so.total)>6000
 ORDER BY to_char(so.order_date, 'MM') desc
```

Output:

```
State Month        Sales
----- --------- --------
TX    September   $8,400 
CA    July        $8,377 
TX    March       $7,700 
TX    March       $8,540 
CA    February   $46,370 
MN    February    $6,400 
CA    February   $24,650
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there may be an issue in both your `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses.

Try:

```
SELECT c.state AS "State",
       to_char(so.order_date, 'Month') AS "Month", 
       sum(so.total) AS "Sales"
  FROM a_customer c
  JOIN a_sales_order so ON c.customer_id=so.customer_id
 GROUP BY c.state, 
       to_char(so.order_date, 'Month')
HAVING sum(so.total)>6000
 ORDER BY to_date(to_char(so.order_date, 'Month'), 'Month') desc
```

I don't have a working instance in front of me at the moment to try it but you need to ensure you are grouping on the same output as you are displaying, in your original example, you are grouping on the full order_date but displaying just the month portion.
The order by in your example will order by the text of the month rather than the actual chronological order.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This worked, but I want to understand the order by better. you are changing order_date to a char value with the month, then you are changing the char value to a date value, represented by a month?

Comment: Effectively you truncate the ORDER_DATE to just the month portion in the TO_CHAR, if you just did that then the order would be just on the month string rather than the month value. Therefore you must TO_DATE it again in order to get a chronological order.